# Solve: $\log_3(5(2^2+3^2)(2^4+3^4)(2^8+3^8)(2^{16}+3^{16})(2^{32}+3^{32})+2^{64})=?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation

> $$\log_3(5(2^2+3^2)(2^4+3^4)(2^8+3^8)(2^{16}+3^{16})(2^{32}+3^{32})+2^{64})=?$$

At a first glance, it seems that I need to do this:

$$\log_3((2+3)(2^2+3^2)(2^4+3^4)(2^8+3^8)(2^{16}+3^{16})(2^{32}+3^{32})+2^{64})=?$$

But afterwards, I can't find an algebric manipulation that will lead me to the solution, I took the exercise out of one of the entry tests of TAU.

Comment: You can of course just calculate it by multiplying out the brackets. The result is 64. I guess you want a different way of doing it. Any requirements?

Comment: This: $$\prod_{k=0}^{n}{\bigg[2^{2^k}+3^{2^k}}\bigg]<3^{2^{n+1}}$$ might help.

Comment: There is a neat way of doing this. It would work with other numbers in a similar set of relationships and doesn't in general depend on the fact that $3-2=1$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since
\begin{align*}
&\phantom{==}(3-2)(3+2)(3^2+ 2^2)(3^4+2^4)\cdots(3^{32}+2^{32})\\
&= (3^2-2^2)(3^2 + 2^2)(3^4+2^4)\cdots(3^{32}+2^{32})\\
&= (3^4-2^4)(3^4+2^4)(3^8+2^8)\cdots(3^{32}+2^{32})\\
&= \cdots\\
&= 3^{64}-2^{64},
\end{align*}
the result is $\log_3(3^{64}) = 64$. The trick is $(a-b)(a+b)= a^2 - b^2$.

Comment: Awesome, I am feeling pretty stupid not able to see this. $+1$

Comment: The app and the site always have the delay. I have encountered several times.